# Change the date format of header inside Apache httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, date, httpd.conf, response-headers

I am trying to set a date header for some files in Apache httpd conf file like this:

```
<filesMatch "\.(css|js|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault A86400
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
   Header set X-Timestamp "%t %D" 
</filesMatch>
```

The date appears in micro seconds, I need to format it in human date format like YY:MM:DD HH:mm.

Any idea how can I do that?

Is it possible to set a formatted date in an environment variable and use it inside the header?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the variables defined here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html to set an header with human readable date time:

```
RequestHeader set AuditDate expr=%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}
RequestHeader set AuditDateTime expr=%{TIME}
```

Results when headers are printed to access log:
    "2019-06-19" 
    "20190619195319"